# Uninitialized constant File::NOCTTY error when I require 'fakefs'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require, rubymine, uninitialized-constant

I am trying to use [FakeFS](http://ozmm.org/posts/fakefs.html) but keep getting an uninitialized constant error when I `require 'fakefs'`:

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fakefs-0.3.1/lib/fakefs/file.rb:26:in `<class:File>': uninitialized constant File::NOCTTY (NameError)
```

I was originally working in RubyMine, but to isolate the problem I wrote a simple hello world script and ran it from the command line, and still get the same error. Here is that script:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'fakefs'
require 'fakefs'

puts "Hello Cleveland!"
```

And here is the error and accompanying stacktrace:

```
>ruby foo.rb
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fakefs-0.3.1/lib/fakefs/file.rb:26:in `<class:File>': uninitialized constant File::NOCTTY (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fakefs-0.3.1/lib/fakefs/file.rb:4:in `<module:FakeFS>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fakefs-0.3.1/lib/fakefs/file.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fakefs-0.3.1/lib/fakefs/safe.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fakefs-0.3.1/lib/fakefs.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from foo.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

I installed the fakefs gem via RubyMine. I'm working on Windows with Ruby 1.9. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Windows doesn't have `NOCTTY` and `SYNC` flags. You can add this method to the `base.rb` file:

```
def RealFile.const_missing const
  const_set const, 42
end
```

Really, I don't know it cause any problems or not in the future but you'll be able to run your script at least. And I think you should write about this at [github](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs)

There is a fork with some windows fixes (this guy commented all flags at all): https://github.com/vertiginous/fakefs

Comment: Adding that method does the trick. Also thanks for pointing out the fork with Windows fixes.